# Wpf TreeViewItem Contextmenu Command binding not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, command, treeview

I want to create a `ContextMenu` for `TreeViewItem`s and pass a parameter as `TreeViewItem` data context (not `TreeView` data context).

I'm getting the error below for the command binding. What is the problem?
I also tried `TreeViewItem`, `MenuItem` and `ContextMenu` as `AncestorType`.
I also tried `AncestorLevel` as `1`, `2`, `3`, but it did not change the result.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TreeView', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DeleteFolderCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

Here is my code:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
   <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"
             BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
         <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ContextMenu>
                  <MenuItem Header="Sil"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteFolderCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView},Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding }"></MenuItem>
               </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ContextMenu` is is not part of the same visual tree as its associated control, so `RelativeSource` bindings do not work.

Bind the `Tag` property of a `TreeViewItem` to the `DataContext` of the parent `TreeView` instead. Then you can access this property through the `PlacementTarget` property on the context menu, which is set to the corresponding `TreeViewItem`.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"
          BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
      <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}"/>
      <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
               <MenuItem Header="Sil"
                         Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DeleteFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                         CommandParameter="{Binding}"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: it is a perfect workaround solution. Thanks. What would the solution be if the tag property was used for another purpose?

Comment: @ErhanUrun Then you could create an attached property and use it the same way.